# Longest item in each group

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find which activity took the longest (1) by facility (giving me 6 different activities) and (2) by facility and department (giving me 11 different activities).

This code only gives my one response when

```
SELECT NOC.FCILTY_ID, NAC.ACTIVITY_ID, NAC.ELAPSED_SECONDS
FROM NAC,  NOC
WHERE NAC.OBS_ID=NOC.OBS_ID
AND NAC.ELAPSED_SECONDS IN (SELECT MAX(NAC.ELAPSED_SECONDS) FROM NAC, NOC
GROUP BY NOC.FCILTY_ID)
ORDER BY NOC.FCILTY_ID;
```

An example of some of the data and the code to retrieve some of the data is given below.

```
SELECT NAC.OBS_ID, NOC.FCILTY_ID, NOC.DEPT_NO, NAC.ACTIVITY_ID, NAC.ACTIVE_SECONDS, NAC.CAT
FROM NAC, NOC
WHERE NAC.OBS_ID = NOC.OBS_ID;

OBS_ID   FCILTY_ID   DEPT_NO   ACTIVITY_ID   ACTIVE_SECONDS  CAT
1        A           a         132           73.9999584      Motion
2        A           a         133           92.000016       Operations
3        A           a         134           198.0000288     Operations
4        A           a         135           54.9999936      Error/Defect
5        A           a         136           79.0000128      Error/Defect
6        A           a         137           57.9999744      Operations
```

Comment: I mean Oracle,sql server,mysql or other?

Comment: Meaning Oracle. (SQL Developer is not a database product, it is only the user interface, or one of the user interfaces, to access Oracle).

Comment: Ok,  I am rather new to sql/oracle.

Comment: Are you trying to get everything in ONE query, or in two separate queries? The former would be rather odd...

Comment: 2 separate queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CTE to add a ROW_NUMBER for each desired grouping,rnf for facility and rnfd for facility and department

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT NAC.OBS_ID, NOC.FCILTY_ID, NOC.DEPT_NO, NAC.ACTIVITY_ID, NAC.ACTIVE_SECONDS, NAC.CAT,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NOC.FCILTY_ID ORDER BY ACTIVE_SECONDS  DESC) as rnf,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NOC.FCILTY_ID,NOC.DEPT_NO ORDER BY ACTIVE_SECONDS  DESC) as rnfd 
FROM NAC, NOC
WHERE NAC.OBS_ID = NOC.OBS_ID)
SELECT NAC.OBS_ID, NOC.FCILTY_ID, NOC.DEPT_NO, NAC.ACTIVITY_ID, NAC.ACTIVE_SECONDS, NAC.CAT FROM CTE
WHERE rnf=1 OR rnfd =1
```

EDIT
For 2 separate queries

```
..WHERE rnf=1 

..WHERE rnfd =1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to join to a subquery.  Here is one way.

```
with maxInterval as 
(select cat theCat, max(active_seconds) longestTime
from etc
group by cat
)

select whatever
from yourTables join maxInterval on cat = theCat
and active_seconds = longestTime
```

Comment: can you please explain the last three lines to me

Comment: can you please explain the last three lines to me?